# Failed return, expects parameter as resource?

Tags: php

```
 function get_total_urls(){
    $total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('url_key' FROM 'urls')");

    $url_total = mysql_result($total, 0);
    echo $url_total;
  }
```

returns error:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

I have been browsing to find the cause, most people get it due to the lack of mysql_query but I'm using that.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  I know the database information is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are [in the deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary This is the first time I've ever written php, you'll have to forgive me.

Comment: There is no `mysql_num_rows` in the code you have given.

Comment: All the more reason to get started the *right* way. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/). :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, I'll have a flick through, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is failing. Therefore, `$total` is receiving `false` instead of the *MySQL resource*. Hence the error.

This is because you are using single quotes instead of back ticks (or nothing) and an incorrect syntax for `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT COUNT(`url_key`) FROM `urls`;
```

**Note:** When in doubt, run your query directly against MySQL (from CLI or PHPMyAdmin) or use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

Comment: Ah, well that sorted the error, but now I have an 'unexpected T_STRING' on line 4.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Post a new question if you can't figure it out:)

Comment: seems to be in the same code, supposedly line 4 is the issue. Which would still be the same line of code being suggested to edit here?

Comment: Seems like you had multiple questions in one…

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function get_total_urls(){
    $total = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`url_key`) FROM `urls` ") ;

    $url_total = mysql_num_rows($total);
    echo $url_total;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is invalid, the correct line in PHP should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(url_key) FROM urls");
```